# Why does require_relative() return a "cannot load such file -- album" error message when "lib/artist" is passed as argument?

Tags: ruby, require, irb

I am trying to load a file into IRB. My working directory is my project's root folder, which has a lib folder. The lib folder has album.rb and artist.rb. When I call require_relative("lib/album") or require("./lib/album") it returns "true". When I call require_relative("lib/artist") or require("./lib/artist"), it always returns the error message, "cannot load such file -- album". It seems as if it can only look for album.rb. What is causing this?

Comment: `artist.rb` requires `album.rb`, doesn't it?

Answer (score -1):

`require` only lets you include a library once. Try switching it around, and doing `require_relative 'lib/artist'` first after reloading IRB. It should work.

Comment: I got the same result.

Comment: "`require` only lets you include a library once." – But it doesn't `raise` an `Exception` if the library has already been loaded, it simply returns `false` normally. "Try switching it around, and doing `require_relative 'lib/artist'` first after reloading IRB. It should work." – `require_relative` doesn't work in IRb *at all*, since it requires relative to the path of the currently executing file and in IRb, there *is no* currently executing file, because it is an interactive command prompt.

Comment: require_relative() does work in IRB. It works with the album.rb file. I've just constructed an Album object and called instance methods, so it must have loaded the file. Furthermore, I get the same error message when I call require("./lib/artist"), so it's not require_relative() versus require(). It's a more general problem with loading files.